# Problems with prolog list matching

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am a prolog beginner. I am trying to build a word generator for a made up language to test my prolog capabilities. Here is my code:

```
generic_consonant(
    ['ሀ', 'ለ', 'ሐ', 'መ', 'ረ', 'ሰ',
    'ቀ', 'በ', 'ተ', 'ኀ', 'ነ', 'ከ', 
    'ꬣ', 'ጠ', '፷', 'ጸ', 'ዂ', 'ፈ', 
    'ፐ', 'ዱ', 'ዳ', 'ዴ', 'ዶ']).

vowel(['ቈ', 'ቊ', 'ቋ', 'ቌ', 'ቍ', 'ኋ', 'ኊ']).

nasal_consonant(['ጙ', 'ዷ', 'ድ', 'ዲ', 'ደ']).

uvular_consonant(['ሠ', 'ወ', 'ዐ', 'ዘ', 'ጙ']).

syllablegen(1, Syllable) :-
    uvular_consonant(Uvular), vowel(Vowel),
    random(0, 7, VowelIndex), random(0, 5, UvularIndex),
    nth0(UvularIndex, Uvular, UvularChar), 
    nth0(VowelIndex, Vowel, VowelChar),

    Syllable = [UvularChar, VowelChar].

syllablegen(2, Syllable) :-
    generic_consonant(Consonant), uvular_consonant(Uvular), vowel(Vowel),
    random(0, 23, ConsonantIndex), 
    random(0, 7, VowelIndex), 
    random(0, 5, UvularIndex),
    nth0(ConsonantIndex, Consonant, ConsonantChar), 
    nth0(UvularIndex, Uvular, UvularChar), 
    nth0(VowelIndex, Vowel, VowelChar),

    Syllable = [ConsonantChar, UvularChar, VowelChar].

wordgen([], _).
wordgen(SyllableNums, Word) :-
    SyllableNums = [Head|Tail],
    syllablegen(Head, Syllable),
    append(Word, Syllable, NewWord),
    wordgen(Tail, NewWord).
```

All the syllablegen predicates are working when I call "syllablegen(1, X)." and "syllablegen(2, X).", but a problem occurs when I am calling wordgen and it gives me an unexpected output which is this:

```
?- wordgen([1, 2],  X).
X = [] ;
X = [_2898] ;
X = [_2898, _2910] ;
X = [_2898, _2910, _2922] ;
X = [_2898, _2910, _2922, _2934]
```

The behavior I was expecting was an output like this:

```
?- wordgen([1, 2],  X).
X = [ዐ,ኊ,ለ,ዐ,ቌ] ;
```

or a derivative of it as randomness exists in this program.

I been working on this for past few hours and I just cannot figure it out for the life of me. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, I'm just bored. I'm building a verbal language based on horn clauses like prolog.

Comment: I think you mixed up the order of arguments to append/3

Comment: One suspicious thing is that `Word` is a parameter of the predicate `wordgen/2` but, the the recursive call does not involve this variable. I mean, both `Tail` and `NewWord` are ground at the recursive call (at least for the first solution)

Comment: This is cross posted on SWI-Prolog forum. [I need help prolog recursion problem](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/i-need-help-prolog-recursion-problem/4252/3)

Comment: Of interest: [Using Definite Clause Grammars in SWI-Prolog](https://github.com/Anniepoo/swipldcgtut/blob/master/dcgcourse.adoc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two small things to fix in `wordgen/2`. First, change the order of the arguments to `append/3` (`append(A,B,C)` succeeds if `C` is the concatenation of `A` and `B`). Second, fix the second argument to the empty list in the first clause.

```
wordgen([], []).
wordgen(SyllableNums, Word) :-
    SyllableNums = [Head|Tail],
    syllablegen(Head, Syllable),
    append(Syllable, NewWord, Word),
    wordgen(Tail, NewWord).
```

Comment: Frickin' backtracking. Thank you very much.